# KnockoutJS & TypeScript (DefinitelyTyped): Adding Properties to Observables

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, knockout-3.0, typescript1.6, definitelytyped

In KnockoutJS, you can add additional properties to your observableArrays such as:

```
class Table {

    items: KnockoutObservableArray<SomeType>;

    constructor() {
        this.items = ko.observableArray<SomeType>();
        this.items.someMethod = ko.pureComputed([...]);
    }
}
```

That said, TypeScript will mark the `someMethod` property as an error and won't compile.

<del>It appears that the above works for `KnockoutObservable<T>`, but not for `KnockoutObservableArray<T>` (using DefinitelyTyped's Knockout definition files).</del>

Is there a way to allow these additional properties without having to resort to the following for every single one?

```
/// Inside a custom definition file
interface KnockoutObservableArray<T> {
    someMethod: any; // Works, but is tedious and pollutes the definitions
    [x: string]: any; // Indexers don't work...
}
```

I am also not keen on using `any` for the parent property's definition.

---

## Edit

Okay, it appears that, in order to get this to work, one needs to use the indexer option and then reference the dynamic property as `this.items['someMethod']()` rather than `this.items.someMethod()`. It looks like the TypeScript spec simply doesn't allow for *dynamic* or arbitrary properties in class definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to attach arbitrary properties to typed objects, the easiest way I've found to do it is to cast the object to `any` when you want to read and write those properties.  So in your case you'd do:

```
 (self.items as any).someMethod = ko.pureComputed();
 var value = (self.items as any).someMethod();
```

This syntax is fairly clean and lets you access arbitrary properties, without losing the general type protection elsewhere.

---

That being said, I'd definitely recommend against this pattern.  Adding arbitrary properties to library objects like this just makes the code a bit more difficult to read and reason about and doesn't really provide any benefit.  Assuming that `someMethod` is some logic specific to the `items`, I would either attach the `someMethod` logic to the parent viewmodel itself, or if there is enough logic related to `items`, pull that logic into its own viewmodel containing both the list of items and related logic.

Comment: Thanks for outlining the casting method - I'm now using that in one instance. But you're right - I should really be moving it to the main VM, or implement a sub-VM. That said, these arbitrary properties used to be very convenient since they were not included in `ko.toJSON` calls - so I'll need to find some other way to keep my objects' serialisation clean.